# Handling Joint Sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

```
A1,A2,A3,A4
A2,A4,A6
A1,A3
A3,A4,A5,A6
A1,A2
A2,A4,A5,A6
```

Let's say we have an input like above each row shows a customer and:

`A[1]` to `A[n]` is a product that a customer has bought what I'm looking for is a  ay to store this in ram to fulfill following questions:

1. `Sup(A , B)` which is the probability of buying `A` and `B` together
2. `Conf(A , B)` which says that if we bought `A` what is the probability of buying `B`

`A` and `B` are sets which contains `A[1] to A[n] (A = {A[1] to A[n]} AND B = {A[1] to A[n]})`.

In other words, we want to find for example if `A = {A2,A4,A6}`.

What is the best way to find the number of times this item is  shown in the input to then calculate `Sup` and `Conf`.

BTW the solution needs to be both memory efficient and time efficient.

Comment: This is a mathematics/statistics question. Bayes comes close...

Comment: that part is no problem my problem however is how to store the input in ram efficiently and how to answer those 2 questions as fast as possible BTW the input size is big more than 1 million lines of data.

Comment: Most efficient *storage* would be a bitmap (bit1 = 1 if A1 is present, etc.) For sparse maps, more complex methods could be used. You could also choose to store the aggregates, instead of recomputing them, etc. (and there is also the *inverted index* method) Good luck!

Comment: iterating through a million lines of input and checking if we have 0 or 1 each time the user ask a question is not ideal for my problem i'm looking for a tree like structure or a graph at least but i cant solve sets with more than 2 elements inside it for example if we draw and edge for each pair of A1 to An i cant figure out if its A1A2 or A1A2A3.